DirectX11 SwapChain Force Texture Format
ID3D11Texture2D* pTexture = nullptr;
HRESULT hrGetBuffer = pSwapChain->GetBuffer(
    0, 
    __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), 
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pTexture)
);

Is it possible to force the texture to come in a specific format? For example, DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM.
Or is there any library that does this?

You did that when you created the texture using ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D . Or you can transform it after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706795/how-to-transform-a-id3d11texture2d-into-any-picture-format

For the swapchain, the format of the 'backbuffer' was provided to DXGI in the CreateSwapChain method or the older D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain.
The valid formats for the backbuffer format is limited and is based on the Direct3D Hardware Feature Level:

DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM is always supported (assuming DXGI 1.1 or later).

DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB are supported on Feature Level 9.3 or later.

DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM, DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT are supported on Feature Level 10.0 or later. They are often used with HDR, and 10:10:10:2 can be used for better gradients even for SDR .

DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10_XR_BIAS_A2_UNORM is optionally supported on some Feature Level 10.0 or later hardware.


See this blog series for more information. In particular the 'old' vs. 'new' handling for sRGB formats.
